# Stop pyzmq receiver by KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, loops, break, termination, pyzmq

Following [this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3ataskwork) example in the ØMQ docs, I'm trying to create a simple receiver. The example uses infinite loop. Everything works just fine. However, on MS Windows, when I hit CTRL+C to raise KeyboardInterrupt, the loop does not break. It seems that `recv()` method somehow ignores the exception. However, I'd love to exit the process by hiting CTRL+C instead of killing it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `zmq.Poller` object seems to help:

```
def poll_socket(socket, timetick = 100):
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
    # wait up to 100msec
    try:
        while True:
            obj = dict(poller.poll(timetick))
            if socket in obj and obj[socket] == zmq.POLLIN:
                yield socket.recv()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    # Escape while loop if there's a keyboard interrupt.
```

Then you can do things like:

```
for message in poll_socket(socket):
    handle_message(message)
```

and the for-loop will automatically terminate on Ctrl-C. It looks like the translation from Ctrl-C to a Python KeyboardInterrupt only happens when the interpreter is active and Python has not yielded control to low-level C code; the pyzmq `recv()` call apparently blocks while in low-level C code, so Python never gets a chance to issue the KeyboardInterrupt. But if you use `zmq.Poller` then it will stop at a timeout and give the interpreter a chance to issue the KeyboardInterrupt after the timeout is complete.

Comment: As of today, I'm still sometimes forced to kill my applications instead of hitting CTRL+C -- very uncomfortable... I'm also working with `zmq.Poller` (thanks for the "for..in" pattern, btw.!), but there are situations where the Poller does not help: 1) using built-in devices (`zmq.device()`), 2) using REQ sockets in case that REP worker breaks. I discovered the following: http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:interrupt, but have found no use of it.

Answer (score 17):

In response to the @Cyclone's request, I suggest the following as a possible solution:

```
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL);
# any pyzmq-related code, such as `reply = socket.recv()`
```

Comment: Excelent. This worked for me (Windows 10). Haven't tried the accepted answer, but it seems you're also using this for your fix.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this going to work in Windows, but in Linux I did something like this:

```
if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: This does not work for me exactly, ``sys.exit()`` is always called -- in the docs, I've found that ``signal.signal(...)`` only sets the signal handler. However, putting ``signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL);`` before the infinite loop solved my problem and it is now possible to terminate the receiver using CTRL+C! So thanks a lot for hint!

Comment: @Tregoreg, you should post your comment as an answer.  I'll upvote it... worked for me, and a lot cleaner than changing how my code handles request handling.

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks for feedback, I did as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try ctrl+break (as in the key above Page Up, I had to look it up, I don't think I've ever touched that key before)
suggested near the bottom of [this thread](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/100). I haven't done anything too fancy, but this seems to work well enough in the cases I've tried.